# Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the following error while "Sync Project with Gradle files"

`Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2`

I have tried uninstalling Android Support Repository and installed it again.

I am using Android Studio 1.5
Android SDK Tools 24.4.1
Android SDK Platform-tools 23.1

Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.2

From Gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

On Clicking "Install Repository and sync project" link I am getting the following error

> Loading SDK information... Ignoring unknown package filter
>   'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all
>   packages. There is nothing to install.
>            Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Comment: Did you end up solving this ?

Comment: @user3793589 I updated to Android Studio 2.2.3. That project was created using a beta version of Android Studio and had support for `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2`. Upon updating to a recent version of Android Studio which by then had constraint layout support in stable release that error went away.

Comment: Thanks for this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated to Android Studio 2.2.3.

That project was created using a beta version of Android Studio and had support for `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2`.

Upon updating to a recent version of Android Studio which by then had constraint layout support in stable release that error went away.